# MySQL remote access using bind-address

Tags: mysql

I am studying MySQL and trying to understand how bind-address works on version 8.
Whenever I put bind-address= 127.0.0.1 / (local machine ip) and then:

```
CREATE USER 'test'@'other_machine_ip' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'xxxxxx';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'test'@'other_machine_ip';
```

Other machine can connect remotely like this, but when I do bind-address=other_machine_ip the mysql doesn't start.

can anyone explain?

Comment: bind address must be one of IP from current machine not other. In other words, bind address is that address which will be used to bind MySQL service with IP and port 3306(default port) and that IP will be used to access mysql  locally or remotely.

Comment: so how can I give access to other machines? only like I did - create user @ other_machine_ip? or there's a file like pg_hba in postgres

Comment: yes you need to create users like **create user username@IP** or you can create user with wildcard which is not recommended like **create user username@'%'**

Comment: You should generally have `bind-address=0.0.0.0`, to allow any other host to connect that can see you. Setting it to 127.0.0.1 only allows connections from the localhost. How you give access to other *users* is a completely separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

`127.0.0.1` is a special IP Address owned by *ALL* IPv4 machines they use to talk to *themselves*, so it *always* refers to the local machine.

If you want machine `A` to talk to machine `B` then the IP Address you give to machine `A` **must** be the IP Address of machine `B`. If you tell machine `A` to connect to `127.0.0.1`, it will try & connect to itself.

The MySQL login you use from `A` will also need to be configured on `B` to be allowed to access the database from `A`, by setting up a password that allows this, e.g.

`grant all privileges on ${DATABASE}.* to '${USERNAME}'@'${MACHINE-A}' identified by '${PASSWORD}'`

(substitute as appropriate)

You also need to be able to route between the two. Check they can both `ping` each other.

MySQL will also need to be listening on port `3306`, as well as a local unix socket, e.g. by adding `port=3306` into the `[mysqld]` section of `my.cnf` on the server, and in the `[client]` section of `my.cnf` on the client.

NOTE: MySQL does **NOT** perform well over long distance or high latency links. You will probably experience unexpectedly poor performance.